# Setting D3 svg.transition to go from slow to fast to slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a D3 graph that allows a user to click a button to take them to a specified node. The button looks like this:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.panGraph(9)">Go to End</button>
```

This button will take the user from wherever they are in the svg at the time of click, to the x and y coordinates of the last node, with the id of 9. On click this function is called:

```
  function panGraph (nodeId:any) {
                svgWidth = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                svgHeight = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);

                for (var i = 0; i < renderedNodes.length; i++) {
                    if (nodeID === renderedNodes[i].id) {
                        ctrl.selectedNode = renderedNodes[i];
                        var translate = [svgWidth / 2 -  renderedNodes[i].x, svgHeight / 2 - renderedNodes[i].y];
                        var scale = 1;
                        svg.transition().duration(4000).ease(d3.easeExpInOut).call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
                    }
                }
            }
```

In  the above function I have all the rendered nodes that have been rendered on the page, once I find the matching id I use its x and y coordinates to center the specified node in the middle of the svg. That all works fine.

I am trying to use some animations during the time that the graph is translating to the specified node on button click. When the user clicks the button that takes him or her to the specified node, is it possible to animate the transition so that the transition initially starts slow, then speeds up, but then slows down again at the end as it gets close to the specified node? Thanks

UPDATE:

The above code with the "ease" incluided gives me this console error:

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Object.d3.ease (d3.js:5844)
at Array.d3_transitionPrototype.ease (d3.js:8838)
at zoomOnNode (DiagramComponent.ts:1128)
at DiagramComponent.ts:1072
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17073)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17337)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25023)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the v3 equivalent to Gerardo's post regarding v4:

```
 svg.transition().duration(1000).ease("exp-in-out").call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
```

For a list of all the easing equivalents from v3 to v4 and other changes:

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: I'm happy that you found the solution! Btw, you can accept your answer after some time.

Answer (score 4):

One (out of several) solution is to use `ease` with `d3.easeExpInOut`, or `d3.easePolyInOut.exponent(x)` with a high exponent (like x=4 or x=5).

See this snippet. Click the circle to see it moving from left to right, starting slow, speeding up and then slowing down again:

```js
d3.select("circle").on("click", function(){
 d3.select(this).transition()
 .duration(4000)
 .ease(d3.easeExpInOut)
 .attr("cx", 360)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200">
 <circle cx="40" cy="100" r="30" fill="teal"></circle>
  <line x1="40" x2="40" y1="100" y2="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
 <line x1="360" x2="360" y1="100" y2="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is the right way to go! Still, it needs some refinement since OP uses v3 while this is v4 style. Please, also add the v3 approach and keep this as a second part for future reference.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, that's exactly what I need. Am I able to use that on the svg.transition line in my code? I updated my code to reflect what I am trying with the ease. I have to be able to access the ease within my function above as this is part of a larger angular component. I seem to be getting a console error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" when I click on my button. I was reading more about d3.ease this morning but what is the best option if I wanted to set the animation to go from fast to slow to fast? I want to provide two options for different situations.

Comment: Found the issue, figure it out in a plunker. +1 to altocumulus. I am using d3 bower version 3.5.17, which causes the "index of undefined" error I noted above in my post. When I switched to Version 4 in my plunker the error goes away and it works fine. Is there a different approach for v3? Also, approach with v3 to transition from fast to slow to fast? Thanks